# Dictionary help in Python3

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to print a formatted layout of a list. I've got the main part down but I can't seem to get the numbering right.

Here's the code:

```
shopping_list = {"eggs": "$2", "milk": "$3.50", "cereal": "$3"}

my_shopping_list = "".join(**n**+". "+item+" "+shopping_list[item]+"\n" for item in shopping_list)

print(my_shopping_list)
```

Basically I want to print the items and price in the format:

{number}. {item} {price}\n

So the results should be:

```
1. eggs $2
2. milk $3.50
3. cereal $3
```

It should work if I add more items into the dictionary

But I do not know what to replace **n** with:

```
**n**+". "+item+" "+shopping_list[item]+"\n" for item in shopping_list
```

I've tried using lists to do this

```
shopping_list = [["eggs", "$2"], ["milk", "$3.50"], ["cereal", "$3"]]

my_shopping_list = "".join(str(n+1)+". "+shopping_list[n][0]+" "+shopping_list[n][1]+"\n" for n in range(len(shopping_list)))

print(my_shopping_list)
```

And it works just fine but I need it to work for dictionary so do I find a way to index a dictionary like a list or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note, you're not using a dictionary comprehension in this code

Comment: Oh, thanks. May I know what is it called then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it right. You can adapt your code to use `dict.items()`

```
my_shopping_list = "".join(str(i+1)+". "+ k + " "+ v +"\n" for i, (k,v) in enumerate(shopping_list.items()))
```

But I would recomend using `str` format, and joining using `\n`

```
print("\n".join('{}. {} {}'.format(i, k, v) \
      for i, (k,v) in enumerate(shopping_list.items())))
```

Comment: What does enumerate() do?

Comment: @vluke `enumerate` will generate for you automatically an index for each item for a iterable. So for example, if you have `l = ['a', 'b', 'c']` , enumerate(l) will yield `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`. Can also check [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html)

Comment: This is perfect, I never knew that function existed. Thanks for your help

Comment: @vluke consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach

```
shopping_list = {"eggs": "$2", "milk": "$3.50", "cereal": "$3"}
my_shopping_list = "\n".join(("{0} {1} {2}".format(i, v[0], v[1]) for i, v in enumerate(shopping_list.items(), 1)))
print(my_shopping_list)
```

**Output:**

```
1 eggs $2
2 milk $3.50
3 cereal $3
```

Comment: Could you explain why you changed what you changed? Im sorta new

Answer (score 0):

Make it readable using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

```
from itertools import count

shopping_list = {"eggs": "$2", "milk": "$3.50", "cereal": "$3"}

c = count(1)
for k, v in shopping_list.items():
    print(f'{next(c)}. {k} {v}')

# 1. eggs $2
# 2. milk $3.50                                               
# 3. cereal $3
```

Comment: May I know why you added "f" Infront of the string and what count from itertools does?

Comment: IMO, that's an unnecessary use of `itertools` once `enumerate` is a built-in function that gives you just that

Comment: `f` before string does formatting a string. Read about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Regarding `count`, please refer link in my answer.

Comment: @RafaelC I agree; there are different ways of doing stuffs. :)

Comment: @Austin agreed :) I appreciate showing the use of `f''` and itertools, but for this problem, I believe that'd be unnecessary dependencies added to project for something as simple as a counter